# substitute record1 (field1) by record1 (field2) -> in fileB

Tags: bash, awk

My question might not be quite clear... so lets get to samples datas...
fileA
162,400
174,402
175,404
187,406

fileB
E-J1-N5,319319,240248,364364,**162162**
F-J6-N1,380380,250250,360360,**162174**
E-J6-N2,380380,240240,364374,**175187**

Wanted output
E-J1-N5,319319,240248,364364,**400400**
F-J6-N1,380380,250250,360360,**400402**
E-J6-N2,380380,240240,364374,**404406**

So I need to substitute all occurrences of field1 (fileA) by field2 (fileA) but in another file, fileB (field $5).

Here is what I though could work. Store in two variables: recordx (field1) and recordx (field2). My NOT working code:

```
#!/bin/bash
for record in fileA
   do
        field1=`cut -d, -f 1 $record`
        field2=`cut -d, -f 2 $record`
        awk -v var1=$field1 -v var2=$field2 -F, '{sub(/var1/,"var2",$5);print}' fileB

   done
```

I get an error :
awk: cannot open 175 (No such file or directory)

Why is awk trying to open a variable ?
Am I heading in a good direction ?

Any help would be greatly appreciated !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue

```
awk 'NR==FNR{
       a[$1]=$2
       next
     }
     {
       match($5,/(...)(...)/,b)
       $5=a[b[1]] a[b[2]]
     }1' FS="," OFS="," fileA fileB
```

#### Output

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next}{match($5,/(...)(...)/,b);$5=a[b[1]] a[b[2]]}1' FS="," OFS="," fileA >
E-J1-N5,319319,240248,364364,400400
F-J6-N1,380380,250250,360360,400402
E-J6-N2,380380,240240,364374,404406
```

Comment: Thanks for your help ! I get an error with your command : awk: line 1: syntax error at or near ,

Comment: @Chargaff Looks you don't have `GNU-AWK`. Are you using Mac OS or Solaris?

Comment: @Jaypal Yes ! With gawk, it works beautifully ! Your line is quite amazing ! Thanks a bunch  !

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (although it is sed and not as elegant as the awk solution):

```
sed '/^...,/{H;d};G;G;s/\(...\)\(...\)\n.*\n\1,\(...\).*\n\2,\(...\).*/\3\4/' file{A,B}
E-J1-N5,319319,240248,364364,400400
F-J6-N1,380380,250250,360360,400402
E-J6-N2,380380,240240,364374,404406
```

- Stuff the first file (fileA) records away in to the hold space (HS) and then delete them.
- When encountering records for second file (fileB) append the HS twice to the pattern space (PS).
- Use the last two three digit numbers as keys for the lookups of the numbers in the appended HS's.

N.B. This assumes **all** numbers in field 5 of fileB will be replaced. If only some, then the lookup/replacement needs to be split into two operations.